# Why the phase shift of an electromagnetic wave or light after reflection is smaller than 0, being in the range $[-\pi, \pi]$?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, conventions

In some reports, the phase shift becomes in the range $[-\pi, \pi]$, for instance on [this website](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FresnelEquations). However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection) gives the range as $[0, \pi]$ instead. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

The first link you quote is about Fresnel equations in general, which may describe both transmission or reflection off a boundary. In this case, the deflection angle is $\theta \in [-\pi, \pi]$ with respect to the boundary, with the negative angles being the transmitted (refracted) part, that is *above* the boundary. The positive angles correspond to the *reflected* part, that is *below* the boundary. For reflection, then, you have $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ $-$ your second link is specifically to *Total Internal Reflection* and hence the reduced range.

Comment: Thanks SuperCiocia very much. Considering the case where the light is incident from glass to air, with the incident angle larger than the critical angle, the total internal reflection occurs. In this case, the reflected light should be shifted by θ∈[0,π] which is the same result shown in the Wikipedia. However, the calculated phase shift arg(Er/Ei) of the total internal reflection on the first website is θ∈[-π,0].